# Total Count in paging query taking more time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, query-optimization

In my below paging query, taking 25 records from 100k records in just 2 seconds. But when I add `TOTROWS` column to my query for returning the total count of records (100k) it is taking more than 1 minute. Is there any method to find total no of records in optimized manner?

Below one is running fast without including `TOTROWS` column in the outer select query.

```
DECLARE @PRODUCTNAME NVARCHAR(200),
        @PAGE VARCHAR(100)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ROWNUM INT = 25
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT 
DECLARE @TOTROWS INT
DECLARE @XY INT

SET @PAGE = 1

SELECT TOP 25 
    ID, NAME 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         TOTROWS = COUNT(ID) OVER() 
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT  
              TP.ID AS ID, TP.NAME AS [NAME],
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TP.ID ASC) AS Row 
          FROM 
              PDF TP 
          <WHERE CONDITIONS>

          UNION ALL

          SELECT DISTINCT  
              TP.ID AS ID, TP.NAME AS [NAME],
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TP.ID ASC) AS Row
          FROM 
              HTML TP 
          WHERE <conditions>) a 
      WHERE 
          ROW > (@PAGE - 1) * 25) XY
```

Below one is running slow after adding `TOTROWS` column in the outer select query.

```
DECLARE @PRODUCTNAME NVARCHAR(200),
        @PAGE VARCHAR(100)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ROWNUM INT = 25
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT 
DECLARE @TOTROWS INT
DECLARE @XY INT

SET @PAGE = 1

SELECT TOP 25 
    ID, NAME, TOTROWS  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         TOTROWS = COUNT(ID) OVER() 
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT  
              TP.ID AS ID, TP.NAME AS [NAME],
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TP.ID ASC) AS Row 
          FROM 
              PDF TP 
          <WHERE CONDITIONS>

          UNION ALL

          SELECT DISTINCT  
              TP.ID AS ID, TP.NAME AS [NAME],
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TP.ID ASC) AS Row
          FROM 
              HTML TP 
          WHERE <conditions>) a
      WHERE 
          ROW > (@PAGE - 1) * 25) XY
```

Comment: **Side note:** ***why*** do you declare `@Page` as a `VARCHAR(100)`, even though you **CLEARLY** use it as a counter / numerical value?? Use the **most appropriate** datatype - always. Since you're using `@Page` as a page number - it should **definitely** be a numerical datatype - `INT` or `DECIMAL(p,s)` but certainly ***NOT*** a string datatype!!

Comment: i changed the data type into int.But still slow only.

Comment: Without a real example that can be executed this is quite difficult to figure out. Have you compared execution plans? Maybe the whole logic is skipped if the column is not being selected. Also, please don't use non-english words here.

Comment: i will start new thread with example.Thank you.